# KeePass kdbx not respecting -pw parameter

Tags: command-line, .net-framework, keepass

If I use the command line `KeePass.exe {kdbx location} -pw:{password}`, all that happens is KeepPass opens minimized and still asks for the password when I click on it. Even putting this in a `ProcessStartInfo` and being explicit with the application directory and arguments results in the same behavior. The kdbx location displayed is correct. Why is it not unlocking the database with the password?

Comment: Does `{kdbx location}` contain spaces?

Comment: Crossposted to [so] [KeePass kdbx not respecting -pw parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38338977)

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068)

Comment: There's KeePass and KeePass2, is it possible the two have different command line formats, and you've read the instructions for the wrong one? Also as above make sure you have no spaces in a single parameter, enclose in quotation marks.

Comment: @Florian The [article on command line options](http://keepass.info/help/base/cmdline.html) also has directions for 2.x versions. That's why I didn't think it mattered.

Comment: @DavidPostill The other post is being voted to be closed. The first vote came in moments after I posted the original thread. I'm not going to waste time with this community's capricious nature. I'm trying to find an answer to my question.

Comment: @Bigsby " I'm trying to find an answer to my question" Then please follow the community rules. They are there for a reason. "I'm not going to waste time" You are wasting **our** time by crossposting. Please remember we are all volunteers here and answering **your** questions in out own spare time and free of charge.

Comment: You're right I hate this system too, especially the random downvoting anonymous people do all the time, like the way someone downvoted your question, I brought it back to zero. One more idea: it could be a character set issue, i.e. maybe your command prompt does not support Unicode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, ultimately, I ended up downloading the source and changing it to accommodate what I needed it to do.